# Find the row numbers in A that match rows in B

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to know the index of the rows in A that match rows in B.

Both A and B are data frames. For simplicity just assume:

```
a1 <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b=letters[1:5])
a2 <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b=letters[1:3])
```

In this case it's supposed to return 1,2,3.

My full dataset has 500k rows and 18 columns.

Comment: Do you have a matrix? A data frame? Something else? Please share valid R code to produce your example data, e.g., `A = matrix(c(1, 3, 2, 4), nrow = 2)` or perhaps `A = data.frame(v1 = c(1, 3), v2 = c(2, 4))`. And similarly for `B`. Please edit your question to update it with this information, don't just put it in a comment. If you have other questions about reproducibility, [see here for lots of great ways to make good, reproducible questions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/903061).

Comment: Maybe `match(paste(B[,1],B[,2],sep="*"),paste(A[,1],A[,2],sep="*"))`. Please provide a sample of your data if you want more-than-a-guess answers.

Answer (score 2):

The `join.keys` function in the `plyr` package provides a key to each unique row across a pair of input data frames, which makes it pretty straightforward to determine which rows from `A` appear in `B`. In the list returned by `join.keys`, `x` is the vector of row identifiers for the first data frame and `y` is the vector of row identifiers for the second data frame.

```
library(plyr)
with(join.keys(a1, a2), which(x %in% y))
# [1] 1 2 3
```

Comment: what if my matrix has more than 2 columns?

Comment: @j20120307 This will work without modification no matter the number of columns.

Comment: what does row identifier mean here? I have c("V1",...,"V18") as my header for both data frames. Each row is a data point and there are 18 features for each data point.

Comment: @j20120307 If two rows have identical data for all 18 features they will have the same row identifier; otherwise they will have a different row identifier.

Comment: Thank you this works. What if I want to know the corresponding row number in A that rows in B matches in A? If A=[[1,2],[2,3],[3,6]] and B=[[2,4],[3,6]], then it returns [NA, 3]?

Comment: @j20120307 `with(join.keys(a1, a2), as.numeric(na.omit(match(x, y))))` returns the first matching row for each row of `a1` that actually matched. If you want the first matching row with `NA` values when there is no match, try `with(join.keys(a1, a2), match(x, y))`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I managed to handle this by add a new column `c(1:nrow(a1))` at the end of a1, then I reorder the group by setkey on all the other columns and then reorder it back by my newly added column at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code :

```
>subset(a1,a1$a %in% a2$a)
```

It returns :

```
>1  a

>2  b

>3  c
```

If you just want column a, you can add :

```
>subset(a1,a1$a %in% a2$a,a)

>1

>2

>3
```

I think it will be fast to do it on your data.